Is it possible to auto open the task pane with a plugin using WOPI?
I have a WOPI environment set up with CSPP, I have successfully passed in an AppSource app via host_install_addins input. However, this add-in asks for consent and after accepting the task pane closes and the user has to re-open it. Is it possible to have it so after consenting, the add-in stays open? I tried editing the XML of the document so that the task pane would automatically open, works in Word on my desktop, but my WOPI environment gives me a generic "Could not open document" error when I try to load this specific document.
(https://i.sstatic.net/kESPUVTb.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/4TyOmdLj.png)
I tried editing the XML in the same way you would for local Word expecting it to work in a similar way, but WOPI just errors. Microsoft have provided a support table suggesting WOPI is supported but I am having no luck, cannot seem to find any other people online who have done this successfully.
table of support for auto opening

Can you please share the error?
